# How can I write this coffeescript so it doesn't refresh my page?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

This is my first Coffeescript function and can't figure out how to get this to not refresh my page after the user clicks and the event is fired:

```
jQuery ->
  $(".answer_link").click -> 
    $val = $(this).attr 'id'
    $id = $val.replace(/answer_link_/, '')
    $input = "#new_answer_" + $id
    $($input).toggle 'slow'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this is a question about `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.
you can use `.preventDefault()` to do this:

```
jQuery ->
  $(".answer_link").click (event)->

    #like this
    event.preventDefault()

    $val = $(this).attr 'id'
    $id = $val.replace(/answer_link_/, '')
    $input = "#new_answer_" + $id
    $($input).toggle 'slow'
```

more info about [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: Just saying `event` seems to be a keyword so I wouldn't use it in this context. Change `event` to `x` or something. This code works fine, and I am just getting to scripts with cs myself, but `event` is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `return false` at the end of the click function like this :

```
jQuery ->
  $(".answer_link").click -> 
    $val = $(this).attr 'id'
    $id = $val.replace(/answer_link_/, '')
    $input = "#new_answer_" + $id
    $($input).toggle 'slow'
    return false
```